# PHP: What's wrong with this foreach with a list of checkboxes? It only works when I select one item from the list

Tags: php, foreach

I have a list of users with uploaded files shown in a table. Each one has a checkbox and I should be able to check one or more, press a button and delete the file reference in the database and send the user an email.

My foreach loop won't work as expected. It does work when I select only ONE user, but it won't work when selecting more than one. **I understand that the foreach loop is the problem, but can't find why.**

### This is the checkbox besides every user:

```
<td> <input name="desecharDocs['.$x['userEmail'].']" type="checkbox"></td>
```

### The HTML shows as expected:

```
name="desecharDocs['usuario1@example.com']"
name="desecharDocs['usuario2@example.com']"
```

...and so on.

### And here's my PHP code:

```
 if(isset($_POST['desecharDocumentacion'])) { 
        $desechar = $_POST['desecharDocs'];
        foreach ($desechar as $key => $value) {

            //Borramos la entrada en base
            $sql = "UPDATE usuarios 
                    SET docFoto = NULL, docDNI = NULL, docCertif = NULL, docVerificada = 0
                    WHERE userEmail = '$key'
                    ";
            $desecharAhora = mysqli_query($conectar, $sql);

              if ($desecharAhora) {
                  echo 'Documentaci&oacute;n desechada para '.$key.'<br>';

                  //Mandamos un mail al usuario
                  $avisar = "SELECT mailNombre, mailAsunto, mailMensaje
                             FROM configMailsUsuarios
                             WHERE mailNombre = 'mailDocDesechada'
                            ";
                  if ($correo = mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($conectar, $avisar))) {
                    $mail->addAddress($key);
                    $mail->Subject = $correo['mailAsunto'];
                    $mail->Body    = $correo['mailMensaje'];
                    if(!$mail->send()) {
                        echo 'El mail no se mand&oacute;: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
                        echo $avisar;
                    } else { echo 'Se envi&oacute; un correo de aviso a '.$key.'<br>';}
                  }
              }
        }
  }
```

Comment: Why do you think the foreach loop is the problem? Have you confirmed that your $_POST is an array?

Comment: I would make the input name `desecharDocs[]` and make the `value` attribute the auto-increment value from the table instead of using the email address. If you only use numeric values, you lessen the chance of error since you are only dealing with on character type (numbers).

Comment: What is this selecting: `$avisar = "SELECT mailNombre, mailAsunto, mailMensaje FROM configMailsUsuarios WHERE mailNombre = 'mailDocDesechada'";`? Seems like it should have a dynamic value in it? Possibly it's selecting the same thing on every loop?

Comment: does the `if ($desecharAhora) {
                  echo 'Documentaci&oacute;n desechada para '.$key.'<br>';` part work? can you see the echo as well as key value for multiple users?